# How to make a small program that can search for words in folder? [PYTHON]

Tags: python-2.7

So I'm trying to write a small program that can search for words within files of a specific folder.

It should be able to search for one word as well as a combination of two words or more. Then it should as a result give a list of the file names that include those words.

It's important that I use dictionaries and that the files are given a number within the dictionary.

I've tried several of things but I'm still stuck. Basically I've been thinking that each words within the file have to be split into strings, and then by searching for a string you get a result.

It's important to note that I'm using unicode utf-8.

Anyone willing to help me?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are trying to reinvent `grep`

Comment: Well I've made a program that can search for one word in files, but without a dictionairy, which is not my purpose.

Comment: word_count = {}
f = codecs.open('filename.txt', encoding = 'utf-8')
for line in f:
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        word = word.lower()
        if word not in word_count:
            word_count[word] = 1
        else:
            word_count[word]=word_count[word]+1


I have to somehow implement the dictionary above into a program. I just don't know if I've done it right. Can I name a list of filenames in a dictionary and how? So each value has a key?